# Calling native method from eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am succeeded to call a c++ library from my JAVA code using JNI.Now I want to load the same. dll from a eclipse plugin and call the library functions.I kept the library in root directory of the plugin folder .
I am getting error like:
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: testproj.testClass.testCall:()V

please help me to resolve that.Why the same code working for Java but not working from plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Got it the package and class name should be same in the plug in and also the dll should be in the same root folder of the .java file where u load the library